# Google Apps script - change the background color of a cell with a hex value from another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm trying to change the background color of a cell with the hex value from another cell. For example, I'd like to make the cell in A2 have a background color of #333333 (which is the text value of cell A1). Here is the code I have so far:

```
function setColor(targetCell) {

  // get targetCell's value (a hex value)
  // set the background of the active cell to the value of targetCell

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var value = ss.getRange(targetCell).getValue();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground(value);
  return cell;

};
```

Right now the code will not run because getRange(targetCell) is not correct, but even when I replace targetCell with something like "A1", I get the error message "You do not have permission to call setBackground (line 9)"

Comment: how are you using that function ? a custom function ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to include this in a spreadsheet with setColor(targetCell) where targetCell is a reference to another cell with a hex value

Comment: Possible dup of other questions that use custom functions to modify a another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, custom function can't modify other cells,

please refer to the documentation about custom function to see their limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be a bug.

(The function is not trying to modify another cell, because getActiveCell() returns the current cell.)

Comment: Upvoted. Though technically true, this isn't a bug. The  accepted answer should instead read `Formulas cannot modify cell format`